# How can I print lines that contain val_b > 20 using as few awk statements as possible?

Tags: awk

Using awk, how can I print lines that contain `val_b > 20`, given the following text file using as few awk statements as possible?

```
2023-08-29 16:27:57.124 | test | t1 | val_a=1 val_b=2 val_c=3 val_d=4
2023-08-29 16:27:58.124 | test | t1 | val_a=1 val_c=3
2023-08-29 16:28:57.124 | test | t1 | val_a=1 val_b=2000 val_c=3 val_d=234 val_e=423
2023-08-29 17:27:57.124 | test | t1 | val_a=1 val_b=20 val_f=332
2023-08-29 17:27:57.124 | test | t1 | val_b=27
2023-08-29 17:27:57.124 | test | t1 | val_b=29 val_c=332 val_d=234 val_e=423
```

This works but it involves 4 awk statements:

```
awk '/val_b/' test.log | awk -F 'val_b=' '{ print $2}' | awk '$1 > 20' | awk '{print $1}'
2000
27
29
```

How can it be condensed to as few awk statements as possible?

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output (for the provided sample input)

Comment: you can use a regular expression to get the number after `val_b=` into a variable. Then use `if(that_variable > 20)`

Comment: [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) is your friend `:)`

Comment: I’d love to give a proper answer, but closing question on StackOverflow is a one-way street  Very annoying. Here's a solution with one awk statement. `awk 'match($0, /val_b=([2-9][1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,})/){print substr($0, RSTART+6, RLENGTH-6)}'`. You can upvote another awk answer .

Comment: Is this a Code Golf exercise?

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** this answers your question "how can I print lines that contain `val_b > 20`"

Here is about as short as I can make it using `awk` and an extended regex that matches only records where `val_b=X` where `X` is 21 or greater:

```bash
awk '/val_b=([2-9][1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,})/' file
```

(note: the default `print` action is called if the regex matches)

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample data in `file` you would have:

```
$ awk '/val_b=([2-9][1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,})/' file
2023-08-29 16:28:57.124 | test | t1 | val_a=1 val_b=2000 val_c=3 val_d=234 val_e=423
2023-08-29 17:27:57.124 | test | t1 | val_b=27
2023-08-29 17:27:57.124 | test | t1 | val_b=29 val_c=332 val_d=234 val_e=423
```

---

**Outputting only the Values where** `val_b > 20`

If your goal is to only output the values where `val_b > 20`, then  you could do:

```bash
awk '/val_b=([2-9][1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,})/ { 
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
    if ($i~/^val_b/) {
      sub(/^val_b=/,"",$i)
      print $i
    }
  }
}' file
```

Which would provide the output of:

```
2000
27
29
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - thank you sir. The comment below the answer had my favorite :)

Answer (score 2):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
{ for (i=8;i<=NF;i++) {
      split($i,a,"=")
      if ( a[1] == "val_b" && a[2] > 20 )
         print a[2]
  }
}
' test.log
```

**NOTES:**

- this assumes *all lines* have the same format as displayed in OP's provided sample input whereby the strings we're intersted in start at the 8th whitespace-delimited position
- if input lines can vary in format from what's been provided and/or the strings of interest could appear anywhere in the line then change `i=8` to `i=1`

Another `awk` idea:

```
awk '
match($0,/\<val_b=[[:digit:]]+/) { split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),a,"=")
                                   if ( a[2] > 20 )
                                      print a[2]
                                 }
' test.log
```

**NOTES:**

- requires `GNU awk` for the `\<` (start of) word boundary
- if the value (right side of the `=`) is not an integer this solution will truncate anything past the initial integer value (eg, `23.22` becomes `23`; `200e+01` becomes `200`); in this scenario the regex could be extended to indicate the end of the field (eg, space, tab, eol, etc)

Both of these generate:

```
2000
27
29
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '20<+($0=$2)' FS='(.* val_b *=)? *'
```

---

```
2000
27
29
```

if you wanna keep the entire row then it's even shorter :

```
awk '20<+$2' FS='.* val_b *= *'
```

---

```
2023-08-29 16:28:57.124 | test | t1 | val_a=1 val_b=2000 val_c=3 val_d=234 val_e=423
2023-08-29 17:27:57.124 | test | t1 | val_b=27
2023-08-29 17:27:57.124 | test | t1 | val_b=29 val_c=332 val_d=234 val_e=423
```

Comment: Nice! It can be even further shortened to `awk -Fval_b= '20<($0=+$2)'`.

Comment: Nice. Not that it was specified but `.* val_b *=` would not parse an entry at line start and `.*val_b *=` would not descriminate between `val_b` and `otherval_b`...

Comment: @dawg : which is fine, since a timestamp-less entry would likely be invalid based on inferring the underlying formatting structure given the examples.

Comment: @steffen : i intentionally placed the `+( )` at the outer layer instead of at `$0 = +$2` just in case `$2` contains a value that gets mangled by `CONVFMT`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Your first solution doesn't produce any output when I run it. The second one which keeps the entire row works fine. The solution provided by steffen works well.

Comment: @WawrzyniecPruski then change `$0=$2` to `$!NF=$2`

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
awk '/val_b/{
        for(i=0;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~"^val_b=") {
            sub(/^val_b=/,"", $i)
            if ($i>20) print $i
        }
     }' file
```

Or with Ruby:

```
ruby -lne 'puts $_.scan(/\bval_b\s*=\s*(\S+)/).
                   flatten.select{|s| s.to_i>20} if /\bval_b\b/' file
```

The Ruby correctly handles `val_b = 123` where the awk does not.

Either prints (with the OP example):

```
2000
27
29
```

Comment: who says `awk` can't handle it :  `awk '20<+$(NF=2)' FS='(.*val_b *=)? *' OFS=`

Comment: Nice terse awk. My comment meant the awk script I wrote -- not awk in general...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short solution with one awk statement:

```
$ awk 'match($0, / val_b=([2-9][1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,})/){print substr($0, RSTART+7, RLENGTH-7)}' f
2000
27
29
```

`RSTART` and `RLENGTH` are set by `match()`. They can then be used to extract the matching substring.

Comment: This will match `otherval_b` too.

Comment: True - I've added a space. For gawk, `\y` word boundary is safer.